# Return a value from entity to view file in symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to return a value from entity to view file. Below is my entity function

```
public function getVisitorName($id)
    {

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SystemVmsBundle:VisitorsDetails');
    $product = $repository->findOneBy(array('id' =>$id));
    $name=$product->getFirstname();
      return $name;
}
```

This is the line in my view file which calls that function

```
<a href="{{ path('visitorsdetails_show', { 'id': entity.visitorId}) }}">{{ entity.visitorName(entity.visitorId) }}</a>
```

Its not giving me any error. But only a blank page. How can i fix this?

This is my controller code

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('SystemVmsBundle:EntryDetails')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

I am trying to fetch the visitors name(from visitors table) corresponding to the visitor id(in entry table).How will i do it then?

Comment: The entity should not contain code about the repository. Please post the code of the function of your controller which display the page.

Comment: Your entity is container aware? Oo

Comment: @IgorPantović I dint get ur qstn..may be coz of i am very new to symfony. :-)

Comment: Which page is coming up blank? The list of entries? (i.e. the page containing the entity.visitorName links) Or the visitor details (i.e. the page opened when a link is clicked)? Is the supplied controller code generating the blank page?

Comment: @redbirdo Index page itself is showing empty!

Comment: If i remove the {{ entity.visitorId }},it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways of doing it:

1) Map your SystemVmsBundle:EntryDetails entity, to SystemVmsBundle:VisitorsDetails as OntToOne by adding field details to your EntryDetails; , and then in twig template just call it via

```
{{ entity.details.name }}
```

2) instead of creating getVisitorName(), it is better to create [twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) for this, with same functionality.

Comment: Thank you pomaxa! I ll try it and tell!!

Answer (score 0):

Your indexAction() is not returning a response object, it is just returning an array of entities. Controller actions should return a Response containing the html to be displayed (unless they are for e.g. ajax calls from javascript). If you are using twig templates you can use the controller render() method to create your response, something like this:

```
        return $this->render('<YourBundle>:<YourViewsFolder>:<YourView>.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        ));
```

When you've corrected that I suspect you'll get an error because $this->getDoctrine() won't work from an entity class. The code you have in the getVisitorName() method just shouldn't be in an entity class.

As @pomaxa has already suggested, I believe there should be a relationship between your EntryDetails and VisitorsDetails entities although I don't know enough about your data from the question to know what type of relationship it should be (OneToOne / ManyToOne). If your EntryDetails entity had a relationship to VisitorsDetails, the EntryDetails class would then contain a $visitorsDetails attribute and methods to get/set it. Then the line in your twig file would look like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('visitorsdetails_show', { 'id': entity.visitorId}) }}">{{ entity.visitorsDetails.firstName }}</a>
```

There is a section on [Entity Relationships / Associations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) in the Symfony Manual.

Also, I hope you don't mind me giving you a little advice:

1. Be careful when you copy and paste code as it appears you have done in getVisitorName(). You have kept the variable name '$product' although there are no products in your system. This sort of thing can cause bugs and make the code more difficult to maintain.
2. I recommend you avoid tacking 'Details' onto the end of entity names unless you genuinely have two separate and related entities such as Visitor + VisitorDetails and a good reason for doing so. I think the entities in your example are actually 'Visitor' and 'VistorEntry'.
3. Unless you are writing a re-usable component, I recommend you use specific variable names like '$visitorEntries' rather than '$entities' in your controller and twig.

In general, the more meaningful your variable names, the more readable, maintainable and bug-free your code is likely to be. Subsequently, it will also be much easier for people on SO to understand your code and give you help when you need it.